# Images raster Mozambique

Tags: raster, data, mozambique

I'm looking for a high resolution raster image for the province of Maputo in Mozambique. I need it to get the elevation and topography for the area of Moamba-RessanoGarcía. 
Anyone knows any website where can I find and download this raster file?

Comment: Landsat on a clear day https://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a DEM. 
There are several world-wide free (money, use) DEM files, including NASA's 30m resulution [SRTM](http://dwtkns.com/srtm/) and JAXA's [ALOS](http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/aw3d30/index.htm) 30m (and even 12.5m) resolution.

Search for the tile/granule that covers your AOI and download it. Usually needs registration